# How do I add social media icons/logos on Blogger?

Tags: javascript, html, blogger, blogs

How do I add aforementioned to my Blogger [blog](https://thengnet.blogspot.com) ?
When editing HTML, I can see from the theme I'm using that Facebook is using

```html
<!-- FACEBOOK SHARE ICON -->
<a class='facebook-ico' expr:href='data:post.sharePostUrl + &quot;&amp;target=facebook&quot;' expr:onclick='&quot;window.open(this.href, \&quot;_blank\&quot;, \&quot;height=430,width=640\&quot;); return false;&quot;' expr:title='data:top.shareToFacebookMsg' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-facebook'/><span class='split'>Facebook</span></a>
```

; LinkedIn is using

```html
<!-- LINKEDIN SHARE ICON -->
<a expr:href='&quot;https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;title=&quot;+ data:post.title' onclick='window.open(this.href, &apos;windowName&apos;, &apos;width=550, height=600, left=24, top=24, scrollbars, resizable&apos;); return false;' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'><span class='share-text'><i class='fa fa-linkedin-square'/>LinkedIn</span></a>
```

; Pinterest is using

```html
<a expr:href='&quot;https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;media=&quot; + data:post.thumbnailUrl + &quot;&amp;description=&quot; + data:post.snippet' onclick='window.open(this.href, &apos;windowName&apos;, &apos;width=550, height=600, left=24, top=24, scrollbars, resizable&apos;); return false;' rel='nofollow'><span class='share-text'><i class='fa fa-pinterest'/></span></a>
```

; Twitter is using

```html
<a class='twitter-ico' expr:href='data:post.sharePostUrl + &quot;&amp;target=twitter&quot;' expr:title='data:top.shareToTwitterMsg' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-twitter'/> <span class='split'>Twitter</span></a>
```

; WhatsApp is using

```html
<a class='bitz' expr:data-href='data:post.url' expr:data-text='data:post.title' href='#' title='Share on whatsapp'><i class='fa fa-whatsapp'/>WhatsApp</a>
```

Issue: some of the buttons only have a link without an icon (like LinkedIn); others have icon & link (Fb, Twitter, WA); others don't appear at all (Pinterest); they're all unanimated.

I'd like to add (animated) icons for Facebook, Instagram, LinkedIn, Telegram, Twitter, WhatsApp and anything relevant (to my blog), non-cumbersome, appealing, popular & used by most social networkers.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use Font Awesome - https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?filename=tryicons_fa-pinterest

Comment: Will give it a check

Comment: Not working simply that way. I was able to add Pinterest, but the moment I started editing other icons, they disappeared.
I noticed "a.facebook-ico{background: #516eab;}
a.twitter-ico{background: #29c5f6;}" somewhere, and I thing they're being transparent.

Comment: The link you shared @s.kuznetsov, is a drawn image.
I tried others I saw on the <link>, and they appear when I add 'color' attribute to the style; only, they don't appear like Fb & Twitter & WhatsApp do, because they're missing class='facebook-ico' in <a> -- tried adding class='pinterest-ico' for Pinterest and relative version for LinkedIn, but they don't seem to exist.

Comment: One more thing: here are the links in the head:
    <link href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>

Comment: In <body>:
 <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
 <script crossorigin='anonymous' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js'/>
 <script crossorigin='anonymous' integrity='sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'/>